# localstack: error emptying s3 bucket archive-bucket. error: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records

Tags: amazon-web-services, localstack

I'm trying to install demo repo of localstack, but it throwing this error when i tried to run `make deploy` as document said.

```
Serverless: Sync S3: error emptying s3 bucket archive-bucket. error: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
Serverless: Sync S3: Error trying to empty the bucket: error emptying s3 bucket archive-bucket. error: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
Serverless: Sync S3: sync error: error emptying s3 bucket archive-bucket. error: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
```

here's mine `aws configure list`:

```
access_key: test 
secret_key: test 
region: us-east-1 
output: json
```

Link of document: https://docs.localstack.cloud/getting-started/quickstart/

Please help, thanks.

Comment: Did you manage to get over this hurdle? I just tried it out, and it works fine, using the latest LocalStack image. 
It seems the serverless tool is trying to reach the real AWS, but that should not happen since the yaml file is configured to interact with the LocalStack endpoint.

Comment: @AncaG after many hours try to solve this, i can't find the solution and i've tried to install it on another computer on VMWare, and it's worked, so i see that it's not the localstack problem, it was some of my software on my computer is conflict with it or something, so for my computer, i just go to the last solution which is reinstall the operating system, so it worked.